# Clarification on the order of an element in the Pohlig-Hellman algorithm for groups whose order is a prime power

Tags: number-theory, algorithms, cryptography, cyclic-groups, p-groups

According to wikipedia:
[image]

Why does $h_k=(g^{-x_k}h)^{p^{e-1-k}}$ have an order that *divides* p. Shouldn't the order divide $p^{k+1}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order of $h_k$ does divide $p$; for $k=0$ this is immediate from the definition, as
$$h_0:=(g^{-x_0}h)^{p^{e-1-0}}=(g^{-0}h)^{p^{e-1}}=h^{p^{e-1}},$$
and so by Lagrange's theorem the order of $h_0$ divides $p$. For every $k\geq0$ we have
\begin{eqnarray*}
h_{k+1}^p&=&\left((g^{-x_{k+1}}h)^{p^{e-1-(k+1)}}\right)^p\\
&=&\left(g^{-(x_k+p^kd_k)}h\right)^{p^{e-1-k}}\\
&=&\left(g^{-p^kd_k}g^{-x_k}h\right)^{p^{e-1-k}}\\
&=&g^{-p^{e-1}d_k}(g^{-x_k}h)^{p^{e-1-k}}\\
&=&\gamma^{-d_k}h_k,
\end{eqnarray*}
which shows that $h_{k+1}^p=e$ by definition of $d_k$, so the order of $h_{k+1}$ divides $p$.